# Syntastic with JSHint fails to detect undefined function calls

Tags: javascript, vim, jshint, syntastic

Yesterday I started using Syntastic and JShint. It seems to be working ok, detecting missing semicolons or maybe an missing parenthesis etc. 
But if I try to call a function that isn't defined or if there is a typo in the function call, I get no errors.
Example:

```
function addElement(e) {
...
}
addElmen(foobar);
```

This obvious spelling error isn't detected. The same goes for varaibles and arguments.

```
function fooBar(firstArgument) {
    console.log(fritArgument);
}
```

I would like this to be flagged as an unused argument and using an undefined variable.

Any ideas on why and how to fix this?

Comment: It seems to work fine here, I get the message `'fritArgument' is not defined.`  Are you sure you're running `jshint` and not some other checker?

Comment: I only have one checker install that I know off. And I do "let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint']" in my .vimrc file.
I can also see this line inside vim.
"[:SyntasticCheck jshint (javascript)] [Location List] [-]"

Comment: Then enable debugging and read the logs.  Set `g:syntastic_debug` to 3, run the checker, and run `:mes`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. I'm quite new to the whole Linux world.

Comment: Run `:let g:syntastic_debug=3`, then `:SyntasticCheck jshint`, then `:mes`.  Read the manual for details.

Comment: Done. Here are the logs. http://pastebin.com/bQGQBDVK 
Don't really know what I'm looking for. Seems like a bunch of raw data from jshint to syntastic.

Comment: The logs show that syntastic is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118624/discussion-between-edvin-and-lcd047).

Comment: Let's not.  Please post an new issue at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues) if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Okey, I will look around some more and see if I can figure it out before posting and issue. Thanks a lot for all your help! Cheers :)

Comment: `addElmen(foobar);` is not an error because both `addElmen()` and `foobar` may be defined in another script or in the "global" scope.

Comment: I see.. bummer. I'm guessing that's a dead end then? There is no way to check if the function is defined in other scripts or the global scope? And what about the case with argument/varaibles typos?

Comment: Check **jshint options reference** (http://jshint.com/docs/options/), you may find something usefull. set this options in **.jshintrc** file per project with *true* and *false* values and controll hinting in the way you want to be.

Comment: Found the problem. I was using my .jshintrc file that was located in my home folder. But there was added another .jshintrc file without my knowledge within the project that set 'undef' to false...